# How to write a generic code to read an html encoded with different encodings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding, html-encode

I'm trying to write a code to read the content of a web page, but I'm not sure of the used encoding in that page, so how can I write a generic code that returns the right string without the strange symbols?
The encoding might be ("UTF-8", "windows-1256", ...).
I've tried to but the UTF-8 but when the page is encoded with the second mentioned encoding I'm having some strange symbols.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("SOME-URL");
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

And here is a link that causes the problem:
http://forum.khleeg.com/144828.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must examine the response text to check this field:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
```

This chars will also get corretly decoded as they are ANSI.
According to data from this tag you should create your [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) object by the [`GetEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzsz3bk3.aspx) method like this:

```
var enc1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");
var enc2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
```

Another way is to use the [.ContentEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentencoding.aspx) property of the HttpWebResponse:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var enc1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.ContentEncoding);
```

Or the [`.CharacterSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.characterset.aspx) property:

```
string Charset = response.CharacterSet;
var enc1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(Charset);
```

Comment: But does that tag always exist in the web pages? and I've mentioned "windows-1256" as an example it might be any other encoding, any suggestions to work around this.

Comment: @Mousa This tag always on pages that used non-standard encoding. But I've updated the answer for this.

Comment: It could be `HttpWebResponse.CharacterSet` instead of `HttpWebResponse.ContentEncoding`.

Answer (score 0):

The page you mention does tell you EXACTLY which encoding it uses, here's the string found there.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
```

Can't you search for a string like this one and act upon this information?